# Initializing uint array produces big number error

Tags: solidity, javascript, arrays, uint256

Very beginner question!
I am having a really tough time initializing an array of uints.
I have a test contract that consists of 1 line to test this and though it compiles, when I view the data in the public variable it throws a bigNumber error that I am not familiar with.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {
    uint[2] public numberArray = [125,546];
}
```

This results in the following error when called:
[image]

I receive the same error when I try and append to an empty array. I'm not sure how to add uints to an array.
The contract was deployed to a JS VM if that matters.

I think it has to be something local because I have pasted in other's work and got the same error.

Comment: Can you share how you try to access numberArray ?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a parameter to the function call, like `0` to get the first element. It looks like you're trying to get the whole array using the default getter but that's not possible, you need to supply the index to return, or create a separate function that will return the whole array.